# KDE Plasma 5.19 desktop environment?

Tags: lubuntu, kde, desktop-environments, kde5

I have Ubuntu 20.04.1. I do have KDE Plasma 5.18.5 desktop environment.

Does anyone knows if KDE Plasma 5.18.5 will Upgrade to KDE Plasma 5.19 for Ubuntu 20.04.1 ?

I do have the PPA too.

Comment: I don't use Kubuntu but LTS releases tend stick to a particular major release of DE, like GNOME. KDE 5.18 and Kubuntu 20.04, both are LTS releases. So, I think KDE won't be updated to 5.19 in 20.04. You can have [KDE 5.19 in 20.10 (beta)](https://kubuntu.org/news/plasma-5-19-testing-in-groovy-gorrila/).

Comment: Thanks... I may think about that.

Comment: FYI: The KDE desktop requires the underlying toolkits/frameworks to be upgraded as well, so it's a major change. You'll note in the Kulfy provided link the following :*Plasma 5.19 has not currently been packaged for our backports PPA, as the release requires Qt >= 5.14, while Kubuntu 20.04 LTS has Qt 5.12 LTS. Our backports policy for KDE packages to LTS releases is to provide them where they are buildable with the native available stack on each release.*"

Comment: Why is Lubuntu tagged?  It is Qt based, but I don't see any connection